# Is it possible to auth user in third party app with their ssh key used to login?

Tags: security, authentication, ssh-keys, pam

I'm writing CLI application secured with strong password. The users supposed to run it on a server inside of secured perimeter over ssh. My users complain it's too annoying to enter the password every time.

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to use user's ssh keys to authenticate them in my app instead of inputting application password. I can't rely on `$USER` because I want bind authentication to user's ssh keys.

I considered `ssh-agent` but it runs on user's machine afaik. I'm considering PAM now, but not sure if it's possible to check the keys the user used to authenticate.

Could anyone suggest if it's possible and where to research?

Comment: What password? The SSH password? So what does it have to do with your app? I understood that users first login to SSH and then execute your app on the remote server.

Comment: I mean application password. User runs the application, inputs the password and app outputs some results.

"I understood that users first login to SSH and then execute your app on the remote server".

Yes, that's right. User logins on remote server with SSH keys. I want my app to ensure user logged in using predefined set of SSH keys instead of inputing password

Comment: Imo, this is more suitable for [su] or [unix.se].

Comment: Is it possible to cross-post it?

Comment: See [Can I find out which ssh key was used to access an account?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15575/119732)

Comment: I have seen it. The problem is it requires sshd logs parsing, I don't think it's reliable and convenient way for production usage.

Comment: Did you check the other answers, not only the first one?

Comment: Yes, I did. And writing script for setting environment variable isn't looking robust in my slightly non-standard security setup. Because anyone with certain privileges can easily rewrite it

Comment: As you can see from the answers to that question, there are no better solutions, at least not with the stock OpenSSH SSH server. If you need a better solution you need a more customizable SSH server.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right. There is no suitable and secure enough solution

Comment: Do you know that you can force a specific command to be executed instead of a shell when authorizing with a specific private key? So if it is acceptable for your needs, your users can have a dedicated private key for a use with your application. And you configure the server to start your application automatically when the key is used. You then might modify the application to check that a direct parent process of the application is `sshd`. Then it may skip the password check. Or you can even have dedicated account for each user of the application.

Answer (score 0):

As Martin Prikryl [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66437554/is-it-possible-to-auth-user-in-third-party-app-with-their-ssh-key-used-to-login#comment117467682_66437554), there is no robust solution other then install custom OpenSSH server. More over, there is probably no way to prove cryptographically that the user utilized certain key to log into the system.

Setting up environment variable (in any way) is not sufficient to prove the user actually owns it.